# Last line aligned to left for Score in Musixtex

Tags: beamer, musixtex

It is needed to configure last line aligned to left for Score in Musixtex (it is needed to move the final bar to left from red line to orange line approximately). The basic code is as follow:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{musixtex}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{?`Qué es \underline{Musixtex}?}
\centering

\begin{music}
    %\let\addspace\relax
    \parindent0mm
    \nobarnumbers
    \instrumentnumber{1} % a single instrument
    \setstaffs1{1} % with one staffs
    \generalmeter{\meterC} 
    %\startextract
    \startpiece 
    \NOTEs\wh{c}\en\bar%
    \NOTes\hl{g}\hu{e}\en\bar%
    \NOtes\qa{fghi}\en%\bar
    \alaligne
    \Notes\cl{qpon}\cup m\ccu l\clp k\ccl j\en
    \setdoubleBAR
    \endpiece%\endextract
\end{music}


\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The current output is as follow:
[image: current]

Just for clarification. After feedback the solved code is as follow:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{musixtex}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{?`Qué es \underline{Musixtex}?}
\centering

\begin{music}
    %\let\addspace\relax
    \parindent0mm
    \nobarnumbers
    \instrumentnumber{1} % a single instrument
    \setstaffs1{1} % with one staffs
    \generalmeter{\meterC} 
    %\startextract
    \startpiece 
    \NOTEs\wh{c}\en\bar%
    \NOTes\hl{g}\hu{e}\en\bar%
    \NOtes\qa{fghi}\en%\bar
    \endpiece
    \hsize70mm\hoffset0mm\parindent0mm
    \startpiece
    \Notes\cl{qpon}\cup m\ccu l\clp k\ccl j\en
    \setdoubleBAR
    \endpiece%\endextract
\end{music}


\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The solved output is as follow:
[image: solved]

Comment: Your output doesn't match the code you're showing. And you definitely shouldn't be using `\centering` here.

Comment: It is needed to move the final bar let's say 3cm left. The red box indicates the current configuration. The orange box is the desired position. That's all.

Comment: It is unclear to me how a bar containing eight notes should be "moved" to a width of only three notes. Do you want to scale it so that it fits into the yellow rectangle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your `\alaligne` line by something like:

```
\endpiece
\hsize100mm\hoffset0mm\parindent0mm
\startpiece
```

...

Comment: Remember that the length of score changes only on the last line...

Comment: Yes, and after the last line you have to reset your original settings.